# Why does my CPU have random 100% usage peaks?

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, cpu-usage

I need your help. It's been since a couple of weeks by now that my cpu reaches peaks of 100% usage on tasks that, before, never needed this much work. And it is pretty annoying, seeing that when the cpu reaches these peaks, the system starts lagging.

When I talk about these tasks, I refer to something simple, like watching an HD video (doesn't matter if it is 720p or 1080p), surfing the web, watching video on youtube (even though, where it suffers the most is when I try to watch some streaming on Twitch).

I already checked if it was something related to the heat, but the temperature never goes over the 80°C.
Also, when I check into the task manager, the process that works the most is the process of the actual application that I'm using (so, if I'm watching Youtube, then the process is chrome.exe, if i'm watching a video the process is vlc.exe and so on).

My System specs is AMD Phenom II x920 x4 2.8ghz (not OC), 8gb ram ddr2 and geforce gtx470, Windows 8.1.

Guys...help! It's so annoying.

Comment: The problems you describe, in my experience, are normally caused by a HDD that is about to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound could you suggest some test that I could run in order to know the health of my hdd?

Comment: There are literally dozens of related questions.  Have you read those?  [Have you done the required research?](http://superuser.com/search?q=hdd+health)

Comment: These are all related to HDD issues, while mine is CPU and, before you said that this problem could be caused by some HDD fail, I didn't even think about it. So no, I've never looked at this HDD issue ;)

It seems to not be this the problem though, because, if I run something from another HDD it still makes the cpu reach the 100% peak for a couple of seconds.

Comment: If HDD is generating tons of I/O errors then your CPU is spending all its time trying to respond to those I/O errors.  I just described my personal experience, something that I have witnessed hundreds of times, over the years.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and share the compressed file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywvmipzw7kdk9ic/HighCPUUsage.rar?dl=0 here you are

Comment: @liveAndrew I took a look at the ETL and posted an answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i tried to stop the process, but the peaks have come back after some time. Should I make the xperf trace while performing some specific action and post it here? Because with the previous one the pc was idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high CPU usage comes from the [Superfetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch) service which tries to create a boot plan (`sysmain.dll!EcbBootPlanImproveSchedule`) to improve boot performance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is your suggestion about how should behave with this service? Is it safe to disable it? Or it is an important service and I should behave in another way (that you might suggest me)?

Comment: leave it always on. Disabling the service would slow down a lot. Also capture a new trace if you still have CPU usage. you can run the command a while before you get the issue again. I limit the file size to 1GB no matter how long it runs.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ztlr88hszzilta/HighCPUUsage0729.rar?dl=0 this is a new trace I just made. Oh gosh this problem is so annoying...

Comment: the new trace shows WmiPrvSE.exe as cause. So a program does a lot of WMI calls. Run this cmd file: http://forum.sysinternals.com/profsvc-using-significant-cpu-wbemcoredll_topic30521_post143023.html#143023 to also capture WMI data. Share the new trace.

Comment: here it is the new trace:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g67ipn3jj5dxvx5/WMItracing.rar?dl=0

Comment: This time the explroer uses most cpu by drawing some text. I can only see 2 WMI calls directly by xperf during capturing. Wait until you see the WmiPrvSE.exe usage again. Run ProcessExplorer all the time and when you see the issue run the WMI capturing cmd again.

Comment: here are another couple of traces I did while the cpu was, again, at 100% (both normal and wmi traces):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhcks9t04ymclc0/WMItracing0730.rar?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij72l7gbpgt65do/HighCPUUsage0730.rar?dl=0

Comment: I still don't see any WMI usage. taskmgr and xperf itself have a high CPU usage and do 2 WMI calls. Run the WMI tracing command longer (several minutes) when the WmiPrvSE.exe  really has high CPU usage.